# What is the difference between std::filesystem::copy() and std::filesystem::copy_file()?

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, std-filesystem

What is the difference between `std::filesystem::copy()` and `std::filesystem::copy_file()` in this code?

```
#include <filesystem>

void testing()
{
    const std::filesystem::path src = "foo.txt";
    const std::filesystem::path dst = "bar.txt";

    std::filesystem::copy(     src, dst, std::filesystem::copy_options::overwrite_existing);
    std::filesystem::copy_file(src, dst, std::filesystem::copy_options::overwrite_existing);
}
```

Docs say:

- `copy()`: "copies files or directories"
- `copy_file()`: "copies file contents"

Since I'm copying a single file and not directories in this example, are these two calls the same?

(I'm using g++ 8.2.0.  Remember to link against libstdc++fs otherwise you'll have undefined references to std::filesystem.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, barring error or cases you do not expect.

If `src` was silently replaced with a directory, they behave differently.  If `dst` exists and is a directory, I believe they'll behave differently.  Some copy options may apply to copy and not to copy_file as well.

But when copying from one file to another file or to a name whose file does not exist, `copy` invokes `copy_file`.

Note, how ever, that someone could delete `foo.txt` and replace it with a directory in between the last time you checked (say the previous line) and the call to `copy` or `copy_file`.  When implementing robust file system interaction, you should not assume the filesystem is in a specific state, and ensure your code is written defensively.  To that end, if you intend to copy one file, use `copy_file`.  (And always check errors.)

Answer (score 4):

With the `copy_options` you're using, and the source file being a file (and not a directory), [`copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy) will call `copy_file`.  This isn't the case if you're dealing with directories, symbolic links, or hard links.